# In excel coolur coding based on Percentage

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

In an excel spreadsheet, I have 2 columns whose maximum sum can be 10. So when user inputs values in 2 columns as 3 & 7. so It 100% . In that case circle will be fully filled with one colour.

In the 2nd case when input will be 2 & 3 then its 50 % so now  the circle will be half filled...

Comment: What 'circle'? It is not at all clear on what you are trying to accomplish. Showing your current effort (working or not) can go a long way towards explaining what you are trying to get done.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 Conditional Formatting:

I am not exactly sure what you are looking for (I would echo Jeeped's comment). It sounds like you may be looking to set some conditional formatting features (sorry if you don't). Here is a quick guide to setting up conditional formatting in Excel. Again, sorry if this is not what you are looking for.

*Edit: Sorry reread your post, if you want a different color for when the sum is less than fifty percent, change "Not equal to 10" to "Not equal to 5".

[image: Conditional Formatting]

[image: Conditional Formatting 2]

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 (VBA):

Again, not sure if this is what you want. You had tagged the question with VBA so here is a possible way to incorporate a macro. It will perform a loop on the column that sums the prior two [to make the value a percentage I did (A+B)*(0.1)] where cells with a value less than 50% are colored red and cells with values that are greater than or equal to 50% are colored green. Hope this helps.

```
Sub STACKtest()
'
' STACKtest Macro

Range("C2").Select
Dim cell As Range
Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then Exit Sub
Const REDINDEX = 3
Const GREENINDEX = 4
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each cell In Selection
If cell.Value < 0.5 Then
cell.Interior.ColorIndex = REDINDEX
Else
cell.Interior.ColorIndex = GREENINDEX
End If
Next cell
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

End Sub
```

Here is my test data using this code:

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]